# What's the difference between Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) and Marshal.SizeOf(default(T))?

Tags: c#

Is there any difference in the purpose, result, and/or performance (across all types) of:

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))
```

and

```
Marshal.SizeOf(default(T))
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a type, the second [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3(v=vs.110).aspx) takes an instance. They both return the size of the associated structure.

The latter method calls the former. This is backed up by the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.cs) in coreclr:

```
public static int SizeOf(Object structure)
{
    if (structure == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(structure));
    // we never had a check for generics here
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    return SizeOfHelper(structure.GetType(), true);
}

public static int SizeOf(Type t)
{
    if (t == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
    if (!(t is RuntimeType))
        throw new ArgumentException(SR.Argument_MustBeRuntimeType, nameof(t));
    if (t.IsGenericType)
        throw new ArgumentException(SR.Argument_NeedNonGenericType, nameof(t));
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    return SizeOfHelper(t, true);
}
```

An important distinction is that when using reference types one of your calls will raise an exception the other wont:

This will succeed:

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(AReferenceType))
```

This will error (null passed to method)

```
Marshal.SizeOf(default(AReferenceType))
```

Comment: Small correction: When you do `Marshal.SizeOf(default(T)` It's not the `SizeOf(object)` overload that's called - it's the `SizeOf<T>()` one (and it's that one which then calls `Marshal.SizeOf(object)`). And of course, if `T` is `object` then an exception would be thrown because `default(object)` is `null`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson sure, so there are 2 extra method calls on the callstack, not one!

Comment: So assuming I am working with types (not instances), it is strictly better to use Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyType))?

Comment: @Haighstrom no! That would be wrong. If `MyType` is an instance of `System.Type` it should simply be `Marshal.SizeOf(MyType)`

Answer (score 4):

Beware of reference types: [Marshal.SizeOf<T> Method (T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261467(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ArgumentNullException The structure parameter is null.

For a reference type, `default(T)` will be `null`, so thats not a good idea.

Comment: Yes this is a very important point. If `T` is a reference type, then `Marshal.Sizeof(default(T))` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In the first call you pass an instance of type Type, which is a reference type.  Its size will be always the same as the size of all reference types.

In the second call, however, you pass a value, which can be of :
1. A reference type, and will be the same size as in the first call.
2. A value type, and now this can vary.  For example, .SizeOf(default(byte)) will return 1, .SizeOf(default(int)) will return 4, .SizeOf(default(long)) will return 8.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the same as between `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int))`, `Marshal.SizeOf<int>()` and `Marshal.SizeOf(0)`.

Internally, they all do the same:

- `Marshal.SizeOf(object structure)` gets type of object at runtime:

  ```
  Marshal.SizeOfHelper(structure.GetType(), true)
  ```
- `Marshal.SizeOf(Type t)` just calls the same method with known type:

  ```
  Marshal.SizeOfHelper(t, true)
  ```
- `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` calls the previous overload:

  ```
  Marshal.SizeOfHelper(typeof(T))
  ```

As for me, I would **prefer generic version whenever type is known at compile time or generic**; `Type` overload whenever type will be known at runtime; and `object` overload when you have an object, not a type. It looks like it is what every method was designed for.

Moreover, Marshal.SizeOf(default(T))` makes its purpose less clear and readable.

Comment: If you know it at compile time you should probably just use `Marshal.SizeOf<KnownTypeAtCompileTime>();`

Comment: @Jamiec You are right again :) Thank you, I will update my answer