# Marshal.SizeOf() for instance of boolean in C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, marshalling

I have an instance t of the following class:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    class TestStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] // I1 has size 1 byte
        public bool Boolean0;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] // U1 has size 1 byte
        public bool Boolean1;
    }

    TestStruct t = new TestStruct();
```

Now if I try to get access the layout of this structure for marshalling, I get inconsistent results between Marshal.OffsetOf() and Marshal.SizeOf(), as the following example shows:

```
 Marshal.OffsetOf(t.GetType(), "Boolean0"); // returns 0 as expected
 Marshal.OffsetOf(t.GetType(), "Boolean1"); // returns 1 as expected
 Marshal.SizeOf(t.Boolean0) // unexpectedly returns 4!
 Marshal.SizeOf(t.Boolean1) // unexpectedly returns 4!
```

If found out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412100/whats-the-difference-between-marshal-sizeoftypeoft-and-marshal-sizeofdefau), the Marshal.SizeOf() internally uses t.Boolean0.GetType() which has the default value 4 and ignores the size specified in the Attribute [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]. This explains, why it returns 4 instead of 1.

Now, is there any way I can obtain the actual unmanaged size of t.Boolean0 (1 byte in this example) by reflection?

Comment: The attribute cannot play a role when you pass t.Boolean0, it only works when Marshal can see the complete type declaration.  Default marshaling for a bool is BOOL, a 4 byte int like it was done in the C language and still done in the winapi.

Comment: So there is no actual "unmanaged size" for a bool, it depends on how the field was declared in the unmanaged code.  Could be 1 byte (like C++), could be 2 bytes (common in COM for a VARIANT_BOOL), could be 4 bytes (like C and the winapi).  You never care about it for a single field since you always marshal the entire struct.  Which you nailed down to 1 byte for the bool with UnmanagedType.U1.  Whether that was correct is impossible to tell from the question, just make sure that Marshal.SizeOf() returns the exact same value as sizeof(TestStruct) in the native code.